# What are case scenarios for BMC Remedy products with Oracle High Availability?

Tags: oracle11g

What are case scenarios for BMC Remedy products with Oracle High Availability ?

I'm Looking at finding better and cost efficient solutions to provide high availability and adhoc reporting options with BMC Remedy and Oracle HA Options including RAC and active Dataguard.
Looking at scenarios for
1. a single node Oracle DB & Active Dataguard to meet separation of reporting and high availability fail over requirements
2. RAC & Active Data guard to meet end to end failover and reporting .

The question is what have other people implemented with option #1 what would the fail over time.